# Beds Online API - How to set the destination of the hotel and currency of the results

Tags: php, api

Beds was provided the request example, but i cant set the destination of the hotel in here..

I just want to set manually the destination and set the currency using this request body given by the beds online.

```
$bedsonline_data = '{
    "stay": {
        "checkIn": "2019-01-01",
        "checkOut": "2019-01-05",
        "shiftDays": "2"
    },
    "occupancies": [
        {
            "rooms": "1",
            "adults": "1",
            "children": "1",
            "paxes": [
                {
                    "type": "AD",
                    "age": 30
                },
                {
                    "type": "AD",
                    "age": 30
                },
                {
                    "type": "CH",
                    "age": 8
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "hotels": {
        "hotel": [
            1067,1070,1075,135813,145214,1506,1508,1526,1533,1539,1550,161032,170542,182125,187939,212167,215417,228671,229318,23476
            ]
    }
}';
```

Where do i need to set that here in request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the [API docs](http://hotelbeds-sdk.github.io/hotel-api-sdk-php/namespaces/default.html) ...the response will deliver a currency symbol.

and the example on [Github](https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php) explains how to set the destination:

```
$rqData = new \hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\helpers\Availability();
$rqData->destination = new Destination("PMI");
```

Comment: @MiksAlibo use the API client; I have no clue how `Destination` would look alike as `JSON`... while it's useless to send static text strings, especially when they provide a wrapper class.

Comment: I am sending that using the `PHP CURL`. That's why i'm using `JSON` format request body.

Comment: @MiksAlibo you are reinventing the wheel ...while there is no valid reason for that. and if you really want to waste your time with that; just checkout the source-code or debug the existing client.